# WCF Session Design

Tags: c#, wcf

I've created a WCF service with a basicHttpBinding used by many consumers. Now, I need to implement a session-based tracking mechanism for keeping a 3rd party connection alive across multiple calls.

I understand that basicHttpBinding doesn't support session state, but I'd like to make the service run in 'Per Session' mode without creating a new wsHttpBinding and breaking my current consumers.

Is there an easy way to implement 'Per Session' mode without potentially breaking my current consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new wsHttpBinding in the app.config and maintain the existing basicHttpBinding for current consumers.  You just need to add a service endpoint to the app.config for each binding.  You may wish to use a different address for the wsHttpBinding.

```
<service name="MyService">
  <endpoint address="http://domain.com/MyService.svc" binding="basichHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" Contract="MyService"/>
  <endpoint address="https://domain.com/MyService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig" Contract="MyService"/>
</service>
```

Now, anyone using the http endpoint will use basicHttpBinding and anyone using the https endpoint will use wsHttpBinding.

This ease of configuration is the beauty of WCF.